# php.ini timezone switching between default and determined timezone

Tags: php, iis, timezone

I am using IIS 6 and PHP 5.3.25.
I needed to determine my timezone to "Europe/Berlin".
So i added this row: `date.timezone = "Europ/Berlin"` in php.ini.

Checking with `phpinfo();`
Firstly it showed me correct timezone:

```
Default timezone: Europe/Berlin.
date.timezone: Europe/Berlin
```

After refreshing both changed:

```
Default timezone: Europe/Paris
date.timezone: no value
```

The result is that my php-application can work properly.

Anyone an idea how to fix it?

Best regards,
BExplosiv

Comment: I'm not using php on IIS but how about setting the timezone in your code like in DateTime class?

Comment: I wish i could, but i am already using a software called SugarCRM and AeSync to synchronize with an Exchange Server. AeSync is producing the error, because of this issue. I am not able to change the code of AeSync since i am not the developer of this software.

Is IIS the root of this error anyway?